# Asterisk issue with ConfBridge

Tags: asterisk

I'm receiving an error when I try to call an extension that leads to ConfBridge() app in my dialplan

Here is the extensions.conf

```
exten => 601,1,Noop()
    same => n,ConfBridge(room-one,default_bridge,default_user,sample_user_menu)
```

here are the definitions in conferance.conf

```
[default_user]
type=user

[default_bridge]
type=bridge

[sample_user_menu]
type=menu
*=playback_and_continue(conf-usermenu)
*1=toggle_mute
1=toggle_mute
*4=decrease_listening_volume
4=decrease_listening_volume
*6=increase_listening_volume
6=increase_listening_volume
*7=decrease_talking_volume
7=decrease_talking_volume
*8=leave_conference
8=leave_conference
*9=increase_talking_volume
9=increase_talking_volume
```

And here is the error that I receive in the asterisk console when I dial 601:

```
== Using SIP RTP CoS mark 5
  -- Executing [601@internal:1] NoOp("SIP/nasko-00000047", "") in new stack
  -- Executing [601@internal:2] ConfBridge("SIP/nasko-00000047", "room-one,default_bridge,default_user,sample_user_menu") in new stack
[Sep 26 00:43:06] ERROR[16686][C-000000be]: app_confbridge.c:1187 join_conference_bridge: Conference 'room-one' mixing bridge could not be created.
== Spawn extension (internal, 601, 2) exited non-zero on 'SIP/nasko-00000047'
  -- Executing [h@internal:1] Hangup("SIP/nasko-00000047", "") in new stack
== Spawn extension (internal, h, 1) exited non-zero on 'SIP/nasko-00000047'
```

The version of the asterisk is 11.5. I've looked at a several tutorials on the internet and this was the basic configuration for all of them, but I can't get it to work and it seems that google does not know much about this error.

If someone is more experianced in this matter, please try to help. 
Thanks in advance

Comment: Turn up debugging and try again.

Answer (score 1):

This works for me:

> exten => 5006005,1,answer()
>       ;same=>n,Set(CONFBRIDGE(user,music_on_hold_when_empty)=no)
>       same=>n,Set(myconference=4000)
>       same=>n,Set(TMP_CONF_COUNT=${CONFBRIDGE_INFO(parties,myconference)})
>       same=>n,verbose(3," 4000 has users:${TMP_CONF_COUNT})
>       same=>n,Set(TMP_CONF_LOCKED=${CONFBRIDGE_INFO(locked,myconference)})
>       same=>n,verbose(3," 4000 has users:${TMP_CONF_COUNT} and lock or unlock:${TMP_CONF_LOCKED}")
>       ;same=>n,Set(TMP_CONF_COUNT=${CONFBRIDGE_INFO(parties,myconference)})
>       ;remove , in confbridge 
>       same=>n,Set(FRAME_TRACE(white)=DTMF_BEGIN,DTMF_END,NULL,IAX,TEXT)
>       **same=>n(Press5MuteAll),ConfBridge(4000,,6016adminuser)**

or a simpler config with less possibility of failing:

```
exten => 50060055,1,answer()
same=>n(Press5Mute),ConfBridge(4000,default_bridge,6016adminuser,sabse_admin_menu)
```

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this same problem using Asterisk 11.6. For me the solution was to load the following modules:

```
chan_bridge.so
bridge_builtin_features.so
bridge_multiplexed.so
bridge_simple.so
bridge_softmix.so
```

Hopefully this save someone else some time.